# Can C++ Compilers be hinted for function inverses?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, symbolic-math

I use python's sympy model to solve a lot of symbolic algebra problems, and when looking to export solutions to c++ for higher performance applications, I've noticed patterns like this appearing a lot in my code:

```cpp
vec4 input_color = vec4(1.0, 0.2, 0.8, 1.0);
vec4 c31 = srgb_to_cie31(input_color);
//c31[2] *= 2.0;
vec4 output_color = cie31_to_srgb(c31);
```

If line 3 is commented out, input_color passes through a function, and immediately through its inverse.  For some "trapdoor" functions, one of these can be expensive or approximate.  Is there any way I can hint msvc / gcc to recognize this, and compile away all of these steps?

Comment: Is your compiler's optimizer turned up? Assuming those two functions are short and straightforward, they'll probably get inlined, and once everything's inlined the compiler will demolish it easily.

Comment: You may want to search the internet for "C++ math library" and see what the library provides.

Comment: What hints are there in the presented code to show that one function is the inverse of the  other?  There are a plethora of functions that don't have inverses.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo This is more for larger, more complicated functions. For example, large order polynomials are trivial to calculate, but finding their inverses can be extraordinarily hard.  Newton's method works fine, but I'd rather not compute it if I don't have to.  What I'm more interested in is if its possible to generically hint a pair of functions like this to be recognized as inverses and compiled away, like how simple operations like addition currently work.

Comment: I'm not aware of any such thing.  AFAIK, the state of the art is still things like "this function is pure".

Comment: Of course, you could add code to the forward function so it caches all its inputs and the resulting outputs in a table, and then the inverse function searches the output table before actually trying to compute the inverse.  Might save time but costs memory.

Comment: Interesting question. I also work sometimes with symbolic stuff translated into compiled code (I work with Maxima). My advice is to push the function / inverse function stuff into the symbolic manipulation, I think it's going to be a lot easier there than in the C++ compiler. The question of what's an inverse function is somewhat subtle and if there are any assumptions to be made, I imagine it will be easier (simpler, more obvious to others or to future-you) to deal with on the symbolic side. Also, if you are specifically working with polynomials, there may be special cases you can exploit.